# Connect PowerBI to Postgres on Heroku (not via ODBC)

Tags: postgresql, heroku, powerbi-desktop

How can I connect PowerBI Desktop (latest version) to Postgres running on Heroku without using ODBC.

I've been researching for hours, and can't get to the bottom of it. When I type all my credentials in I get the following error:

[image: error on connection]

Has anyone ever managed this?

I tried the [suggestion here](https://community.powerbi.com/t5/Power-Query/Connecting-to-PostgresSQL-hosted-on-AWS-RDS/td-p/135666), but that didn't do anything, I still get the error.

I am on a regular Heroku account, so I don't have access to Heroku Private Spaces ...etc.

Answer (score 0):

While your question is not a literal duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58731886/connect-heroku-postgres-to-powerbi), due to the no-ODBC requirement, that post has an answer that will work without ODBC.

Check out the [solution here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58731886/connect-heroku-postgres-to-powerbi/77574948#77574948) for how to get Power BI desktop AND service **connected to a Heroku Hosted Postgres Database WITHOUT ODBC**.