# Connect Excel to Heroku Postgres Database

Tags: excel, postgresql, heroku, powerquery

I've set up a Heroku Postgres database on my app using the Hobby-basic tier, and successfully inserted some rows into my tables, which I can verify through the CLI.

Now I'd like to use Excel to explore the contents of those tables.

[From the documentation I can find](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/import-data-from-external-data-sources-power-query-be4330b3-5356-486c-a168-b68e9e616f5a?redirectSourcePath=%252farticle%252fbf941e52-066f-4911-a41f-2493c39e69e4&ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US), it seems I should be able to...

- Install the [Ngpsql data provider for ProgreSQL](https://github.com/npgsql/Npgsql/releases) (version 4.0.10 - later versions are not compatible with Excel apparently)
- Select **Data > Get Data > From Database > From PostgreSQL Database**
- Provide the hostname and database name [given on the Credentials tab of data.heroku.com](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgresql-credentials)
- Click OK, and enter my username and password from that same credentials page

Unfortunately, I have yet to accomplish this successfully.

- If I enter the server exactly as listed on the credentials page,

  eg. `ec2-xx-xxx-xx-xx.xxx.amazon.com`

  I get:

  > Unable to connect
  >
  > We encountered an error while trying to connect.
  >
  > Details: "An error happened while reading data from the provider: 'The remote certificate is invalid according to the validation procedure."
- If instead I annotate that hostname with  `postgres://` in front, I'm able to reach a dialog to enter my username and password credentials, which I again paste from the Heroku page. But then I get a similar error:

  > Details: "An error happened while reading data from the provider: 'No such host is known'"

I've also tried appending `:PORT` at the end, where PORT stands for the port number provided on the Heroku Postgres Credentials tab, with the same results. And I tried pasting the whole URI from the credentials tab, but Excel complains that the hostname must be at most 128 characters.

I'm sure I must be doing something silly like providing the host name in the wrong format or with the wrong protocol, but I haven't found documentation of the right string to use, and the error messages are not yielding strong leads.

[Browsing past Q&A, I found this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58731886/3064164), which I thought might be applicable if PowerBI and Excel use a similar implementation, but [the connection string described in the link](https://www.reddit.com/r/Heroku/comments/iqtqsq/connect_heroku_postgresql_to_power_bi/g582mj5?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x&context=3) does not appear to be accepted by Excel. (It says "The supplied server or database name is invalid.")

Can you recommend ways that I can view my data, or other troubleshooting steps I should try?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aha, I think I've got it now. I was mistakenly on the 32-bit version of Excel, so the instructions at [the reddit thread linked above](https://www.reddit.com/r/Heroku/comments/iqtqsq/connect_heroku_postgresql_to_power_bi/g582mj5/?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x&context=3) weren't working with the 64-bit driver I had. Fixing my Excel version, they worked like a charm.

So here's what I did:

- [Installed the PostgreSQL ODBC driver from here](https://www.postgresql.org/ftp/odbc/versions/msi/) (psqlodbc_13_00_0000-x64.zip)
- Installed 64-bit version of Excel
- Selected **Data > Get Data > From Other Sources > From ODBC**
- In the From ODBC Window, selected...

  - Data source name (DSN): (None)
  - Advanced options > Connection string: `Driver={PostgreSQL Unicode};Server=ec2-xx-xxx-xx-xx.xxx.amazon.com` (Using the host from the Heroku Postgres credentials tab)
- Clicked OK to reach the credentials dialog

  - User name & Password: from credentials tab
  - Credential connection string properties:

    `PORT=HEROKU_PORT;DATABASE=HEROKU_DATABASE;POOLING=True;MINPOOLSIZE=1;MAXPOOLSIZE=20;HOST=HEROKU_HOST;COMPATIBLE=2.2.3.0;USER ID=HEROKU_USER;PASSWORD=HEROKU_PASSWORD;SSLMODE=require`

  (Substituting the relevant info from the credentials tab for `HEROKU_PORT`, `HEROKU_DATABASE`, `HEROKU_HOST`, `HEROKU_USER`, and `HEROKU_PASSWORD`)

...and I was able to import my data successfully.

Comment: i also change `SSLMODE=allow`, and it works