# Can Heroku postgres database connect to power BI?

Tags: python, database, postgresql, flask, powerbi

I pretend create on simple application with Python + Flask + Postgres and deploy using Heroku. But it is important for my application that can be possible connect my deployed database with a power bi dashboard?

Is it possible with an application that was deployed using Heroku?

Its only a question

Comment: Why would your application being deployed in Heroku be prohibitive for using Power BI specifically? Am I missing something? Why not just try it out and see if it works as you expect…?

Comment: Sure, why not? When you have the network connections and user credentials, it works fine. This depends on you, not on Heroku or Power BI.

Comment: Duplicate of [Connect Heroku Postgres to PowerBI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58731886/connect-heroku-postgres-to-powerbi)